# converter entrada em segundos para dias, horas, minutos em segundos em relação a dia em outro planeta. Código em C

Tags: c

Preciso converter a passagem do tempo de outro planeta para dias, horas, minutos e segundos na terra.

A questão é, eu vou receber um `int` (variável `seg`) referente aos segundos passados em Júpiter e preciso saber quanto tempo se passa na terra.

```
dia = (seg / 35760); 
hora = (seg / 3600) - (dia * 24);
minuto = (seg % 3600) / 60;
segundo = (seg % 60);
```

35760 representa a quantidade de segundos que dura um dia em Júpiter. (9 horas e 56 minutos)

A entrada é: `267547464242`.

A saída esperada é: 7481752 dias, 3 horas, 32 minutos e 2 segundos.

Mas a saída que meu código está apresentando é:

> 7481752 dias, -105243308 horas, 4 minutos, 2 segundos.

Fiz a mesma lógica para outros planetas, e deu certo, apenas esse que não funciona.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: acho que vc vai precisar pegar o resto da divisão, que é o que sobra, para calcular os outros `` periodos (resto do dia calcula hora, resto da hora, calcula minuto, etc). O operador de resto no `javascript` é percentual `%`. Por exemplo `267547464242 % 35760` vai dar 12722, ou se seja isso é o que sobra da divisão dos dias, que são as horas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, no cálculo das horas esse `dia * 24` é a causa do problema. Como o total de dias é `7481752` (mais de 7 milhões), ao multiplicar por 24 será um número maior ainda (mais de 170 milhões), e subtrair isso do total de horas (que é `seg / 3600`, cerca de 74 milhões) acaba dando esse resultado aí.

Eu acho mais simples descontar os dias do total de segundos, assim fica mais simples calcular as horas:

```c
dia = seg / 35760;
seg %= 35760;
hora = seg / 3600;
seg %= 3600;
minuto = seg / 60;
segundo = seg % 60;
```

Ou seja, depois de calcular a quantidade de dias, eu faço `seg %= 35760`, que é o mesmo que `seg = seg % 35760`: a variável `seg` recebe o resto da divisão de `seg` por 35760. Ou seja, eu pego somente o "excedente" em segundos, que seria o mesmo que descontar a quantidade de dias desse total. No caso, esse valor é 12722.

Com isso eu posso simplesmente dividir 12722 por 3600 para obter o total de horas. Depois, eu pego o resto da divisão por 3600 para obter o "excedente" e divido por 60 para obter os minutos. Por fim, pego o resto da divisão por 60 para pegar o excedente em segundos.

Assim, o resultado será 7481752 dias, 3 horas, 32 minutos, 2 segundos.

---

Assumindo, é claro, que todas as variáveis são de algum tipo que suporte o valor `267547464242` (por exemplo, se você estiver usando um tipo de 32 bits, ele não suportará tal valor).

Fiz o teste em uma máquina Ubuntu 20, com gcc 9.3.0 e só funcionou se usar `long`, pois o `int` não suporta este valor.

Comment: deu certin! muito obrigado!